# How to access storage device related events with Zeitgeist?

Tags: filesystems, python, zeitgeist

I am trying to get my mind around Zeitgeist, using the [Python DBus API](http://zeitgeist-project.com).

To get the latest accessed files and application is not so hard, here is what I do:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from zeitgeist.client import ZeitgeistDBusInterface
from zeitgeist.datamodel import Event, Interpretation, TimeRange, \
 StorageState, ResultType

zg = ZeitgeistDBusInterface()
events = zg.FindEvents(
 TimeRange.always(),
 [Event.new_for_values(interpretation=Interpretation.ACCESS_EVENT)],
 StorageState.Available, 3, ResultType.MostRecentEvents)

for e in events:
    event = Event(e)
    subjects = event.get_subjects()
    for s in subjects:
        print "subject", s.text, s.uri
```

The interpretation flag `Interpretation.ACCESS_EVENT` returns all matching events, i.e. files and application accessed. [Much more interpretation flags are available](http://zeitgeist-project.com/docs/0.8.2/ontology.html#symbol-interpretation), but I do not succeed in getting results from events other than with `Interpretation.EVENT_INTERPRETATION` and its subclasses. More specifically I would like to access `Interpretation.DATA_CONTAINER`
 and its subclass, but it never returns any result.

So am I doing something wrong in that case? Could you suggest anything?